# A C#-style Event object in C++

Tags: c++, event-handling

I wanted to make an Event object (similar to C# events) for use with a custom UI I'm writing.  The Event should allow multiple consumers (observers) to attach to any given event and not leave dangling pointers if an observer disappears without explicitly detaching from it.  It should also be thread safe, i.e. listeners should be able to attach or detach themselves from any thread.  Finally, it should give me compilation errors if I try to dispatch an event with incorrect arguments, or attach to an event with an incorrect function signature.

My solution looks like this:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>

class Non_Copyable
{
public:

    Non_Copyable() = default;
    Non_Copyable(Non_Copyable const &) = delete;
    Non_Copyable & operator = (Non_Copyable const &) = delete;
};

template<typename T>
class Event_Base : Non_Copyable
{
protected:

    using event_pair = std::pair<std::weak_ptr<void>, std::function<T>>;

    template<typename P, typename Q, typename... Args>
    void Attach_Internal(P(Q::*f)(Args...), std::shared_ptr<Q> const & p)
    {
        auto w = std::weak_ptr<Q>(p);

        assert(!Attached(w));

        auto l = [w, f](Args... args)
        {
            if (auto locked = w.lock())
            {
                return (*locked.get().*f)(args...);
            }
            else
            {
                return P();
            }
        };

        listeners.emplace_back(std::weak_ptr<void>(w), l);
    }

    void Detach_Internal(std::weak_ptr<void> const & p)
    {
        assert(Attached(p));

        auto found = Find(p);

        if (found != listeners.end())
        {
            listeners.erase(found);
        }
    }

    bool Attached(std::weak_ptr<void> const & p)
    {
        return Find(p) != listeners.end();
    }

    void Clean()
    {
        listeners.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(listeners), std::end(listeners), [&](event_pair const & p) -> bool {
            return p.first.expired();
        }), std::end(listeners));
    }

    typename std::vector<event_pair>::const_iterator Find(std::weak_ptr<void> const & p) const
    {
        if (auto listener = p.lock())
        {
            return std::find_if(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), [&listener](event_pair const & pair)
            {
                auto other = pair.first.lock();

                return other && other == listener;
            });
        }

        return listeners.end();
    }

    std::vector<event_pair> listeners;
};

template<typename T>
class Event : public Event_Base<T>
{
public:

    template<typename P, typename Q, typename R, typename... Args>
    void Attach(P(Q::*f)(Args...), std::shared_ptr<R> const & p)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> guard(mutex);

        this->Attach_Internal(f, p);
    }

    void Detach(std::weak_ptr<void> const & p)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> guard(mutex);

        this->Detach_Internal(p);
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args && ... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> guard(mutex);

        if (!this->listeners.empty())
        {
            this->Clean();

            auto listeners_copy = this->listeners;

            for (auto const & listener : listeners_copy)
            {
                if (auto locked = listener.first.lock())
                {
                    listener.second(args...);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    int Count() const
    {
        return this->listeners.size();
    }

    std::recursive_mutex mutex;
};
```

Some questions...

**Is my event object thread safe?**

The public interface of Event is protected with a recursive_mutex.  I chose recursive because it's quite possible that an event handler will detach the listener from the event its handling, or create objects that themselves will attach to that same event.  This is also why I make a copy of the collection before dispatching the event.

**Is my use of shared_ptr and weak_ptr correct?**

The Event object maintains a vector of *weak_ptr* to listeners and I'm using the *Clean()* function to remove all disposed *weak_ptr* before dispatch of the event.  This is a way for Event to know when to delete a listener from its collection (the listener weak_ptr will fail to lock).

**Some things I don't like about it**

Consumers cannot attach to events in their constructors because shared_from_this() is invalid in a constructor.  For this reason Consumers need an Initialise.

std::recursive_mutex [is considered harmful](http://www.codingstandard.com/rule/18-3-3-do-not-use-stdrecursive_mutex/), though in this context I'm not sure that applies, does it?

It's probably quite slow, though as it's for UI events I don't expect any high frequency calling to happen.

Must use shared_ptr/weak_ptr in order to detect when listeners have dropped.  I could I suppose make it part of the contract of use that listeners detach when they destroy themselves but... who reads the comments anyway?

**Are there any improvements I could make to this code?**

Here's some test code (append to above to use in cpp.sh or compile elsewhere).

```
class Producer
{
public:

    Event<void()> & On_Void_Event() {
        return on_void_event;
    }

    Event<void(int)> & On_Int_Event() {
        return on_int_event;
    }

    Event<void(int, int)> & On_Int_Int_Event() {
        return on_int_int_event;
    }

    Event<void(int, int, int)> & On_Int_Int_Int_Event() {
        return on_int_int_int_event;
    }

    void Fire_Events()
    {
        on_void_event();
        on_int_event(1000);
        on_int_int_event(1000, 2000);
        on_int_int_int_event(1000, 2000, 3000);
    }

private:

    Event<void()> on_void_event;
    Event<void(int)> on_int_event;
    Event<void(int, int)> on_int_int_event;
    Event<void(int, int, int)> on_int_int_int_event;
};

class Consumer : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Consumer>
{
public:

    Consumer(int id) : id(id) {}

    void Initialise(Producer * producer)
    {
        assert(producer != nullptr);

        producer->On_Void_Event().Attach(&Consumer::Handle_Void_Event, shared_from_this());
        producer->On_Int_Event().Attach(&Consumer::Handle_Int_Event, shared_from_this());
        producer->On_Int_Int_Event().Attach(&Consumer::Handle_Int_Int_Event, shared_from_this());
        producer->On_Int_Int_Int_Event().Attach(&Consumer::Handle_Int_Int_Int_Event, shared_from_this());
    }

    void Handle_Void_Event()
    {
        std::cout << id << " Handling a void event" << std::endl;
    }

    void Handle_Int_Event(int value1)
    {
        std::cout << id << " Handling an int event (" << value1 << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    void Handle_Int_Int_Event(int value1, int value2)
    {
        std::cout << id << " Handling an int, int event (" << value1 << ", " << value2 << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    void Handle_Int_Int_Int_Event(int value1, int value2, int value3)
    {
        std::cout << id << " Handling an int, int, int event (" << value1 << "," << value2 << "," << value3 << ")" << std::endl;
    }

private:

    int id;
};

int main(void)
{
    auto producer = std::make_shared<Producer>();

    auto consumer1 = std::make_shared<Consumer>(1);
    auto consumer2 = std::make_shared<Consumer>(2);
    auto consumer3 = std::make_shared<Consumer>(3);
    auto consumer4 = std::make_shared<Consumer>(4);

    consumer1->Initialise(producer.get());
    consumer2->Initialise(producer.get());
    consumer3->Initialise(producer.get());
    consumer4->Initialise(producer.get());

    producer->Fire_Events();

    return 0;
}
```

For completeness I added two other event types, *Event_Functor* and *Event_Predicate*.  The former executes a function on the return result of each dispatch invocation , allowing the object firing the event to "gather" return results into an array, for example.  The latter executes a predicate on the return result of each dispatch invocation, terminating dispatch if the predicate returns true.

I have a feeling using this in a observer pattern has a little of the code-smell about it but I imagine them being useful if you want to query your set of listeners for some return result.

```
template<typename T>
class Event_Functor : public Event<T>
{
public:

    template<typename F, typename... Args>
    void operator()(F functor, Args && ... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> guard(mutex);

        if (!this->listeners.empty())
        {
            Clean();

            auto listeners_copy = this->listeners;

            for (auto const & listener : listeners_copy)
            {
                if (auto locked = listener.first.lock())
                {
                    functor(listener.second(args...));
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Event_Predicate : public Event<T>
{
public:

    template<typename P, typename... Args>
    bool operator()(P p, Args && ... args)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> guard(mutex);

        if (!listeners.empty())
        {
            Clean();

            auto listeners_copy = this->listeners;

            for (auto const & listener : listeners_copy)
            {
                if (auto locked = listener.first.lock())
                {
                    if (p(listener.second(args...)))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `Event` is *almost* threadsafe

Why almost? Well, you don't take the lock in `Count`. That means that some thread could be making changes to your object while some other thread spontaneously decides to call `Count`, which will then be subject to a race condition. Even if you do read-only accesses, as long as the underlying object is not atomic, you have to lock.

Apart from that issue, `Event` seems to be threadsafe, at least as far as I can see.

## Why `std::recursive_mutex`?

You do not do any recursive locking. There is absolutely no need for a `std::recursive_mutex`, as far as I can see. A normal `std::mutex` will do the job just fine.

To answer the question you posed: No, the fact that `std::recursive_mutex` is considered harmful does not apply here. However, you are not using any of the special functionality of it anyway, so why bother?

## Other Things

1. About your inheritance scheme:

   ```
   class Event_Base : Non_Copyable
   {
   ```

   Just don't. Don't do this. This is not the C++ way to do things, and can lead to all sorts of trouble down the road. For example, what about this:

   ```
   int main() {
       std::unique_ptr<Non_Copyable> p = std::make_unique<Event_Base>();
   }
   ```

   The behavior of that code is undefined, because `Non_Copyable` has no virtual destructor. And this is just one of the issues you are prone to run into when abusing inheritance, apart from your code becoming more and more inefficient.
2. What is the point of `Event_Base`? Do you plan to have other classes inherit from it? If yes, do add a virtual destructor, now! (See point 1)

   However, if I am honest, I really dislike the idea of having a base class as a kind of mixin or interface. The thing is this: Unless I am a child class of `Event_Base`, there is absolutely nothing I can do with an object of that class, since its whole interface is protected.

   Inheritance is not a zero cost abstraction in C++, and should be used sparingly, especially when performance is critical (which is not the case here, however). In your case, I would advocate for just joining the two classes `Event_Base` and `Event` into a single type. If you want to keep the `Event_Base` around, I could also imagine a different approach to tackling this issue: Convert `Event_Base` into a kind of event container (which it currently is not very far from) and replace instances of it as a superclass with member variables.
3. `Event::operator()` takes arguments by universal reference, but you don't do perfect forwarding. That means that you are locking yourself out of the benefits of move construction, which is usually the reason to use universal references in the first place. Whether this matters here at all is somewhat unclear to me and depends on your use case (do you ever expect a listener function moving from its arguments?). Still, it is weird to not see `std::forward` around there.
4. You can reduce the redundancy in the template parameter for `Event` while also improving type safety a little. What I mean is that the return type of the event functions you construct should always be void, since the result is discarded anyways. This enables you to actually reduce the template parameter from the full-blown function type to just the argument types, removing the need for writing out `void(...)` all the time and preventing the case in which somebody does not pay attention and tries to pass information through the return, which will inevitably end up in discarded-value-hell. As an added benefit, the lambda `l` in `Attach_Inner` would also become a lot simpler.

Comment: @Robinson Please don't retroactively add any code or change the code you posted! If you have more things you want an opinion about, open up another (follow-up) question. About the mutex issue: The lock guard lives exactly for one function call each, then the mutex is unlocked again. Since a single thread cannot call more than one function at the same time, it is guaranteed by definition that the mutex will only be locked once at a time. The multi-lock case only occurs if you are doing recursive shenanigans (which you aren't), hence the name.

Comment: Yes, I just read that in the Help section.  Actually I don't think recursive shenanighans can happen with operator().  I've protected against modifying the collection in a handler (attach or detach) by copying the listener collection... I think you're right on this.

Comment: Having said that there are paths to recursive shenanighans I can imagine in UI components.  Object 1 fires event, Object 2 handles event and modifies some state in Object 1, Object 1 fires event in response (... explosion ...).  However I can think of a few UI patterns where this cannot happen, which I think I'll apply when designing the widget library.

Comment: @Robinson If I think about it, you are right. However, this would requires passing an `Event` to itself, which seems a very questionable practice in the first place. If you want to allow that, than you have to indeed stick with `std::recursive_mutex`.

Comment: Just to add to this, I don't think std::forward the arguments is very safe, i.e. we don't ever want move semantics of arguments to event handlers (UB after the first dispatch I would have thought).

Comment: @Robinson I don't think so. The dispatch happens entirely in `operator()`, and you don't keep any references to its arguments around. The arguments are consumed only once, so you are not running any risk here as far as I can see (however, you would also have to alter the lambdas you are calling to also take arguments by rvalue-ref to make use of move semantics here.